# Crypting passwords on sign up and sign in

Tags: php, sql, pdo, md5, registration

I have the registration system on my website set up to where when the user signs up the password is an md5'd mixture of the email and password that they signed up with. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work properly. Here's the code:

On Signup:

```
$user = strip_tags(substr($_POST['email'],0,32));
$pass = strip_tags(substr($_POST['password'],0,32));
$cleanPass = crypt(md5($pass),md5($user));
$date = time();

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (password, email, first, last, date)
        VALUES(:password, :email, :first, :last, :date)");
```

On Sign in:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$user = strip_tags(substr($_POST['email'],0,32));
$pass = strip_tags(substr($_POST['password'],0,32));        

$cleanPass = crypt(md5($pass),md5($user));

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT email,password FROM users WHERE email=:email AND password=:password limit 1");
```

Comment: you can always use AES encrypt functions of mysql to encrypt and than later on decrypt your data.

Comment: with md5 you wont be able to decrypt that password.

Comment: MD5 is a "1 Way algorithm", you're not gonna be able to decrypt that later, it's a hashing method(which means 1 way)

Comment: I understand that, and I'm not wanting to decrypt it, What the script is doing is inserting an md5'd email/password combo, and when they sign up it does the same thing and matches it.

It works for most people, but not others, and I don't know why.

Comment: "1 Way Algorithms" are called hashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a combo of user/pass when storing the data, what you might wanna conisder is the length of the crypting mechanism. Normally when you do that you don't crypt the 2 md5's of the user&pass, but instead you do something like

```
$cleanPass = md5( $user.$pass );
```

If you also want to store the user, you shouldn't md5 that. If you want to store the pass, md5 it.

Does this help ?